# Trying to make the program add a string after an id

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I am trying to make a button take me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/7/delete/
well with url i added it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/7. without the '/delete' am trying to add, but i don't quite know how, even after some research it's still not working.

related view

```
def Warehouse(request, pk):
  Warehouse = warehouse.objects.get(id=pk)
  items = item.objects.all()

  context = {
      'items': items,
      'warehouse': Warehouse,
  }

  return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/warehouse.html', context)
```

related url

```
path('admin/Inventory_Management/item/<str:pk>/', Warehouse, name="change_"),
```

button

```
<a href="{% url 'change_' item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
```

I tried the following, but as i expected,  it didn't work...

```
<a href="{% url 'change_' item.id/delete %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
```

sorry, if this is a silly question. I am not a great programmer yet.
any help appreciated! please help!

Answer (score 0):

To go to `...admin/Inventory_Management/item/7/delete/` you have to declare an url that match this url. so your path should be

```
path('admin/Inventory_Management/item/<str:pk>/delete', Warehouse, name="change_"),
```

and your template should be

```
<a href="{% url 'change_' item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
```

**note:** if you are trying to delete an item, you have to declare another controller. your `Warehouse` doesn't seems to be deleting anything.

Comment: @AliReda-M can you please flag the answer as correct